# AWS EC2 jupyter notebook python error install scipy packages using pip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scipy, pip, jupyter-notebook

Please remove if this is not the right place.

I am using graphlab-create-1.7.1-coursera (ami-346a7755)

I already installed all dependencies.

Pandas installation has no problem.
But when I tried to install SciPy, error occurs

I tired this command in the notebook.

```
!pip install scipy [--use-wheel] [--no-cache-dir]

Collecting scipy
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading scipy-0.16.1.tar.gz (12.2MB)
    100% |################################| 12.2MB 38.8MB/s 
[?25hInstalling collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-h2CE_T/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zF3Fxl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-h2CE_T/scipy/setup.py", line 253, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-h2CE_T/scipy/setup.py", line 250, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-h2CE_T/scipy/setup.py", line 175, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy/setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-h2CE_T/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zF3Fxl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-h2CE_T/scipy
```

So how can I install the scipy package? Where can I start?

```
!pip list

alabaster (0.7.6)
appnope (0.1.0)
apt-xapian-index (0.45)
awscli (1.6.2)
Babel (2.1.1)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
bcdoc (0.12.2)
boto (2.33.0)
botocore (0.73.0)
certifi (2015.4.28)
chardet (2.0.1)
Cheetah (2.4.4)
cloud-init (0.7.5)
colorama (0.2.5)
configobj (4.7.2)
decorator (3.4.0)
docutils (0.12)
funcsigs (0.4)
functools32 (3.2.3-2)
gnureadline (6.3.3)
GraphLab-Create (1.7.1)
html5lib (0.999)
ipykernel (4.0.3)
ipyparallel (4.0.2)
ipython (4.0.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jmespath (0.5.0)
jsonpatch (1.3)
jsonpointer (1.0)
jsonschema (2.5.1)
jupyter-client (4.0.0)
jupyter-core (4.0.6)
Landscape-Client (14.12)
librato-metrics (0.4.9)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (1.3.1)
meld3 (0.6.10)
mistune (0.7.1)
mixpanel-py (3.1.1)
mock (1.3.0)
multipledispatch (0.4.8)
nbconvert (4.0.0)
nbformat (4.0.0)
nose (1.3.7)
notebook (4.0.5)
numpy (1.10.2)
numpydoc (0.5)
oauth (1.0.1)
PAM (0.4.2)
pandas (0.17.1)
path.py (8.1.1)
pbr (1.8.0)
pexpect (3.3)
pickleshare (0.5)
Pillow (2.3.0)
pip (7.1.2)
prettytable (0.7.2)
ptyprocess (0.5)
pyasn1 (0.1.8)
pycurl (7.19.3)
Pygments (2.0.2)
pyOpenSSL (0.13)
pyparsing (2.0.1)
pyreadline (2.1)
pyserial (2.6)
python-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu1)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2)
pytz (2015.6)
PyYAML (3.10)
pyzmq (14.7.0)
qtconsole (4.0.1)
requests (2.3.0)
rsa (3.1.2)
setuptools (19.1.1)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
six (1.5.2)
snowballstemmer (1.2.0)
Sphinx (1.3.1)
sphinx-rtd-theme (0.1.9)
sseclient (0.0.8)
ssh-import-id (3.21)
supervisor (3.0b2)
terminado (0.5)
testpath (0.2)
tornado (4.1)
traitlets (4.0.0)
Twisted-Core (13.2.0)
Twisted-Names (13.2.0)
Twisted-Web (13.2.0)
urllib3 (1.7.1)
wheel (0.24.0)
zope.interface (4.0.5)
```

Comment: not really a solution, but try installing anaconda. let me know if you need details how to.

Comment: Thank you @EzerK, I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4PrYQOShnE) and installed anaconda, but the jupyter from the public IP still does not recognize the anaconda. Although`$which python` returns `/home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: just to make sure, have you closed your terminal and reopened it?

Comment: Yes, I did close the terminal and reopened it. The ipython in the terminal is working completely fine. The gap here is, the AMI has a default jupyter notebook on the go. One does not need to ssh to install anything while being able to enjoy the notebook by just opening a browser using the public IP. And it is this webpage version jupyter that cannot pick up the anaconda.

Comment: I did not know about that option (the built in notebook),let me know your exact ami and maybe I can try and emulate your situation and find a way to make things work.

Comment: Thank you very much @EzerK, the AMI was ami-346a7755. But I think I found a direct [solution](http://yangjie.me/2015/08/26/Run-Jupyter-Notebook-Server-on-Amazon-EC2/)